# Add wxWidget to sublime text 3

Tags: c++, sublimetext3

I'd like to use wxWidget with sublime text 3.
I add the path of wxWidget in my system variables and a the inclure folder to my Project but I still Can't include any .h in m'y script. 
The error is :No such file or directory.

I don't know how i Can do It.

Comment: You're going to need to provide more information like a minimal version of a program that doesn't work, how you're trying to build it, and what changes you made.

Comment: Oh sorry ! Before going any further, is it even possible to inlude wxWidgets or gtkmm to sublime text 3 ?

Comment: If you mean compile a program that uses those libraries, yes. Note however that Sublime isn't an IDE, so in order to get it to work in Sublime you need to know how to do it manually first.

Comment: Yes, perfect ! You mean with build systems ?

Comment: Yes, in Sublime a `sublime-build` file provides the instructions that tell some external tool how to conduct the build when you try to build, for example by compiling a file. The problem that you're experiencing seems like whatever you've told the build to do, it's not fully working as expected.

Comment: Okay. So I use sb3 and wxWidgets 3.1.1. I compiled It with : [code](mingw32-make.exe –f makefile.gcc BUILD=release MONOLITHIC=0 UNICODE=1 SHARED=1 USE_OPENGL=1 USE_ODBC=1) command. Then I add C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\include to my variable environment and wrote #include <wx/wx.h> in my code. I use the simpliest build system for g++ compiler. So I am wondering what should I add to the build to make that library work ? A -I$(wxWidgets-3.1.1/include) somewhere ?

Comment: You mean you compiled wxWidgets with the `make` command? It's still unclear exactly what code you expect to compile and exactly what build system that you're trying to use.